How can I fit a circle into the gap between an ellipse and the coordinate axes?
Consider an ellipse with the equation $\frac{\left(x-ar\right)^{2}}{a^{2}}+\frac{\left(y-br\right)^{2}}{b^{2}}=r^{2}$. How would I fit a circle with an equation $\left(x-k\right)^{2}+\left(y-k\right)^{2}=k^{2}$ in the small gap between the ellipse and the coordinate axes?
When the ellipse is a circle, e.g. $a=5, b=5, r=25$, the circle equation $\left(x-k\right)^{2}+\left(y-k\right)^{2}=k^{2}$ works with $k=\left(3-2\sqrt{2}\right)ar$. But as soon as $a$ or $b$ or $r$ is changed, it breaks. How would I fit a circle in such space?
Desmos link: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/pifjys6a1h
(play around with the $a$ and see)

Edit: Thanks to @Blue's answer, I created this Desmos graph for future reference: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/dgrpsygsnn

What have you tried? Can't you get k by expressing that they have one point in common

FYI: Defining $p:=ar$ and $q:=br$ for simplicity, I find
$$k = \left(\sqrt{p+q}-\sqrt{p}\right)\left(\sqrt{p+q}-\sqrt{q}\right)$$
but my derivation is a bit messy.

@Blue Thank you very much, can you post your work if you don't mind? I don't mind if it's messy. I got up to
$$
k=\left(3-2\sqrt{2}\right)ar
$$
Which is pretty close enough to your general equation of $k = \left(\sqrt{ar+br}-\sqrt{ar}\right)\left(\sqrt{ar+br}-\sqrt{br}\right)$.

@DavidNyan10: Done!

Here's an interesting follow-up question: What happens when the ellipse is rotated (but still tangent to the coordinate axes)? Equivalently, if $P$ is some point on the director's circle of an ellipse, with $\ell$ and $m$ being the perpendicular tangents from $P$, then what are the radii of the circles tangent to $\ell$, $m$, and the ellipse? (Even more generally: What about when $P$ is any exterior point, with not-necessarily-perpendicular tangents to the ellipse?)

@Blue You just broke my brain, but I'm assuming you mean something like this?
https://cdn.nekonyan.fun/image_2024-06-16_210131316.png

@DavidNyan10: "I'm assuming you mean something like this?" That's indeed what I mean (at least, before considering non-perpendicular tangents.)

@Blue Best I can do is manually by hand XD
https://cdn.nekonyan.fun/image_2024-06-17_165841088.png
I'm still in second year of college I am not capable of such mathematics yet TwT. But we can probably create a new question and let the internet figure it out for us.

Defining $p:=ar$ and $q:=br$ for simplicity, we can parameterize the points of the ellipse and circle by
$$E:(p+p\cos\theta,q+q\sin\theta) \qquad C: (k+k\cos\phi,k+k\sin\phi) \tag1$$
so that the corresponding tangent vectors are
$$E':(-p\sin\theta,q\cos\theta) \qquad C':=(-\sin\phi,\cos\phi) \tag2$$
So, "all we have to do" is solve the three equations $E=C$ and $E'\propto C'$. (This essentially matches the philosophy of the setup of @c'est's answer, but I've used parametric equations and the tangent vectors instead of Cartesians and normals.)
To convert the trig expressions to a polynomial form, define $s:=\tan(\theta/2)$ and $t:=\tan(\phi/2)$ so that
$$\cos\theta=\frac{1-s^2}{1+s^2} \qquad \sin\theta = \frac{2s}{1+s^2} \qquad \cos\phi=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2} \qquad \sin\phi=\frac{2t}{1+t^2} \tag3$$
(This is the standard tangent half-angle substitution strategy.) Then our equations are
$$\begin{align}
p(1+s^2) &= k (1+t^2) \tag4 \\[4pt]
q (1+s^2) (1+t)^2 &= k(1+s)^2(1+t^2) \quad\to\quad
q (1+t)^2 = p(1+s)^2 \tag5 \\[4pt]
p t (1-s^2)  &= q s (1-t^2) \tag6
\end{align}$$
We can now eliminate $s$ and $t$ from the non-linear system. For this, I resort to Mathematica's Resultant[] function. The result(ant), ignoring extraneous factors, is this quartic equation in $k$:
$$k^4 -4k^3 (p + q) + 2k^2 (2 p^2 + 3 p q + 2 q^2)- 4k p q (p + q)+ p^2 q^2=0 \tag7$$
We can invoke the Quartic Formula for the roots, but that's crazy. Again, I just used Mathematica and did a bit of simplification. Knowing the answer, I can make the "obvious"-in-retrospect observation that $(7)$ factors into quadratics (for non-negative $p$ and $q$):
$$
\left(k^2 - 2 k (p +\sqrt{pq} +q) + pq\right) 
\left(k^2 - 2 k (p -\sqrt{pq} +q) + pq\right) = 0 \tag8$$
Ultimately, we have four roots of the form
$$
k\;=\;\left(\;\sqrt{p+q} \;\pm_1\; \sqrt{p} \;\right) 
\left(\;\sqrt{p+q} \;\pm_2\; \sqrt{q} \;\right) \tag9$$
where $\pm_1$ and $\pm_2$ are independent. These correspond to the four ways an axes-tangent circle of radius $k$ can also be tangent to the axes-tangent ellipse; for the desired "gap" circle, we take both signs to be "$-$". Done!

Addendum:
The points of tangency are given by
$$\left(
p \left(1 \pm_1 \frac{\sqrt{p}}{\sqrt{p+q}}\right), 
q \left(1 \pm_2 \frac{\sqrt{q}}{\sqrt{p+q}}\right)
\right)$$
That is, the points of tangency are offset from the ellipse's center left-or-right by $\dfrac{p\sqrt{p}}{\sqrt{p+q}}$, and up-or-down by $\dfrac{q\sqrt{q}}{\sqrt{p+q}}$, making the corners of a rectangle.

Follow-up question: How would one find the intersection point(s) between the circle(s) and the ellipse? I'm guessing turning the equations into parametric form and then equating x with x, y with y, but how would one get a point A=(x, y) from that? If you don't mind, can you solve x and y in terms of a, b, r, and/or k?

@DavidNyan10: Done (again)! :)

If the ellipse $\mathscr{E}\to \frac{(x-a r)^2}{a^2}+\frac{(y-b r)^2}{b^2}-r^2=0$ and the circle $\mathscr{C}\to (x-k)^2+(y-k)^2-k^2=0$ are tangent then substituting $y$ between we obtain a polynomial $p(x)$ such that
$$
p(x) = c_1(x-x_1)^2(x^2+c_2 + c_3),\ \ \forall x
$$
this fact is due to tangency (double root at the tangent point $x_1$). This is equivalent to
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
 a^4 b^4 r^4-4 a^4 b^3 k r^3+6 a^4 b^2 k^2 r^2-4 a^4 b k^3 r+a^4 k^4-c_1 c_3 x_1^2 & = & 0\\
 -4 a^4 b^2 k r^2+8 a^4 b k^2 r-4 a^4 k^3-4 a^3 b^4 r^3+8 a^3 b^3 k r^2-4 a^3 b^2 k^2 r-c_1 c_2 x_1^2+2 c_1 c_3 x_1  & = & 0\\
 2 a^4 b^2 r^2-4 a^4 b k r+6 a^4 k^2-8 a^3 b^2 k r+6 a^2 b^4 r^2-4 a^2 b^3 k r+2 a^2 b^2 k^2+2 c_1 c_2 x_1-c_1 c_3-c_1x_1^2  & = & 0\\
 -4 a^4 k+4 a^3 b^2 r+4 a^2 b^2 k-4 a b^4 r-c_1 c_2+2 c_1 x_1  & = & 0\\
 a^4-2 a^2 b^2+b^4-c_1  & = & 0\\
\end{array}
\right.
$$
now using Groebner bases we can eliminate $\{c_1,c_2,c_3,k\}$ obtaining a polynomial in $x_1$. Assuming $\{a = 9,b = 8, r = 20\}$ the polynomial is
$$
x_1(x_1-180)(17 x_1-2800) (259200 + 17 (x_1-360) x_1) = 0
$$
with roots
$$
x_1 = \left\{
\begin{array}{l}
 0 \\
 \frac{2880}{17} \\
 180 \\
 \frac{180}{17} \left(17-3 \sqrt{17}\right) \\
 \frac{180}{17} \left(17+3 \sqrt{17}\right) \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$
Our solution for the case study is $x_1 = \frac{180}{17} \left(17-3 \sqrt{17}\right)$. Follows a MATHEMATICA script to implement those calculations.
ell = ((x - a r)/a)^2 + ((y - b r)/b)^2 - r^2
cir = (x - k)^2 + (y - k)^2 - k^2
res = First[Eliminate[{ell == 0, cir == 0}, y]] - c1 (x - x1)^2 (x^2 + c2 x + c3)
coefs = CoefficientList[res, x]

parms = {a -> 9, b -> 8, r -> 20};
coefs0 = coefs /. parms;
equsr = Eliminate[coefs0 == 0, {c1, c2, c3, k}] // FullSimplify
solsx1 = Solve[equsr, x1]
x1 /. solsx1 // N
ell0 = ell /. parms /. {x -> x1} /. solsx1[[4]]
cir0 = cir /. {x -> x1} /. solsx1[[4]]
Solve[{ell0 == 0, cir0 == 0}, {y, k}]


